# Should I make a large array local?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 20 by 10 array consisting of doubles and short strings (fewer than 15 chars each). This array is used only inside a function when it is called. The strings are constant only the doubles vary.

Should I leave this array local to the function? Any consideration that I am not aware of?

I am in the process of planning this function and array. The array might have additional types, most likely some enum types, so I don't have any concrete code to show yet. All I know is the approximate size and dimension of the array.

Comment: Could you post some code? Should help us give you a direction.

Comment: Are you having problems with this setup?

Comment: You have an array of multiple types?

Comment: do you have Strings or doubles in the array... I'm confused

Comment: Without knowing the specific code: If you don't need it outside of your function then keep it local. If functions call the array very frequently to where you have to rebuild the array a lot, maybe consider putting it outside of the function, but in general keep things local whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, the array does have multiple types, even more types than I currently have, perhaps some enum types too. I don't have problem with the code, just want to know if it should be local to the function or be outside of it.

Comment: @RJIGO People are asking to see the code not because they think you have a problem with it, but more likely to understand your dilemma.

Comment: @kekoa I am not hiding the code, from my comment, you can tell that I am still thinking about the issue (types not fully fleshed out, etc.). I only know the extent of the array size, the exact code is not there for me to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply *cannot* have a local instance of an array.

Arrays are reference types so the actual memory is always allocated on the heap.

So: Yes, do keep your (reference-to-an) array variable local if that fits its usage. And it does:

> This array is used only inside a function

Comment: If you *really do* need a local array, that's what `stackalloc` is for. I've yet to see a place where it was needed, though. The whole BCL only uses it in a few dozen classes.

Comment: @Gabe - Right, but indeed so exotic that I decided to ignore it.

Comment: This is kind of splitting hairs; this isn't C++, you generally never "point" to a pre-existing heap location without having and copying the reference you got when you created it. So, if you declare a variable within a method that goes out of scope when the method exits, from the perspective of the developer it's "local" regardless of where memory is allocated. Even local value types can be placed in the heap; the decision to put them on the stack is a CLR implementation detail that isn't always true.

Comment: @KeithS - absolutely, but the splitting starts with the word 'large' in the title. This suggests memory-use optimization.

Comment: "You simply cannot have a local instance of an array" - The fact it is not on the stack does not mean it is not "local". local refers to the scoping not whether it's stack/heap memory allocation.

Comment: @weston - that's why I specifically mentioned 'instance'. And responded to the word 'large'.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, from a readability/understandability standpoint I would make the array local, so that others who may come in and look at this code later can understand the usage and scope of the array. If your posterity can tell by inspection that the array could only ever be used by the one function it's declared inside, then if they need to make changes they know that the scope of the change, and of the testing they will have to do, is similarly limited to code paths using that function.

On the downside, if this array is needed many times and its values don't change, then from a performance standpoint it makes sense to widen its scope, thereby lengthening its lifetime so you're not creating and GCing this array unnecessarily. You may make it static if the class will be instantiated many times but always uses the same set of values (or most of them). If you do this, I'd document it saying that it's only used in the one function (unfortunately documentation can stay unchanged long after statements made in them become false, but at least you're doing your part to inform future coders)

It's really up to you; we can't tell from your question what issues you may be having with this code that might indicate changing or not changing it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about things, unless you are incredibly worried about memory usage (which isn't much of an issue these days).

Answer (score 2):

Currently the local variable is instantiated on every call.

If you put the array variable and it's declaration outside of the function then it will not start with zero values for the `double`s and you will need to clean it up before you can use it.

But without seeing code we cannot advise you on whether that will be a good or bad move, but there's the difference for you.